# What scientific studies compare electric muscle stimulation versus resistance training?

Tags: weightlifting, muscle-gain, injury, physical-therapy, medicine

I know this is a wide open topic with countless nuances, but I need to start somewhere.  Will someone please provide a reference to scientific literature comparing the effects of electric muscle stimulation to weight lifting and other forms of resistance training.  I am especially interested in how this applies to healthy normal individuals.

Answer (score 1):

[This meta-analysis](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34417404/) claims that

> The findings indicate that training with NMES [Neuro-Muscular Electric Stimulation] results in virtually identical strength gains compared with conventional strength training when training volume is matched. If training with NMES is preferred, the stimulation frequency type (regular or Burst Mode Alternating Current) can be chosen according to preference without loss of effectiveness.

Mind, this is for similar training volume and only applies to *strength*, not necessarily hypertrophy.

Comment: It should be noted that these studies are using NMES/EMS to cause the muscle to contract *against an external resistance*, which is very different to the TENS treatments often used to manage pain, in which the electrical stimulation is applied without external resistance. It isn't clear which of these two the question was asking about.

Comment: I’ve downvoted because you’re overlooking a critical point: strength is task-specific. While this meta may have found that NMES works as well as voluntary contraction for gains in isometric contraction strength, NMES probably isn’t going to increase your squat in any circumstances at all.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Strength may be task-specific, but there's still a huge amount of carry-over between tasks, especially in lesser-trained individuals. For example DOI 10.3390/life10090184 was a study in order adults that found that isometric NMES training significantly improved performance in dynamic tests.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Is that a belief or do you have any evidence to back that up?

Comment: @DavidScarlett Sure, just having voltage running through your body is not EMS/NMES.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov It is unusual, though quite appropriate and polite to explain a down-vote on SE.  You are a rare true gentleman.

Comment: I up-voted the answer because it is informative and useful.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton - "Overall, NMES cannot be considered as a surrogate training method, but rather as an adjunct to voluntary resistance training. " and "Although a growing number of studies have suggested that intervention based on NMES+ have a strong potential in enhancing as well as preserving muscle function, there is still no clear consensus on the effectiveness". Most of the other included studies say much the same. What they DO suggest (Which is interesting) is that time under load is a huge factor in strength gains.